# How to boost premium offers in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to put premium (sponsored) offers at the top of the list. I also need to use decay function to boost new offers a little bit.

I came up with this idea:

```
{
   "sort": [
      {
         "_score": "desc"
      }
   ],
   "from": 0,
   "size": 15,
   "query": {
      "function_score": {
         "query": {

         },
         "functions": [
            {
               "exp": {
                  "created_at": {
                     "scale": "14d",
                     "decay": 0.1
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "script_score": {
                  "script": {
                     "lang": "painless",
                     "inline": "doc['is_sponsored'].value ? 100 : 1"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Since I use decay "exp" function, sometimes new offers are shown above premium old ones because of multiplying function results.

Premium old offer:

Score is 0.0061177 * 100 = 0.6177

New regular offer:

Score is 0.99 * 1 = 0.99

As you can see, new regular offers can have higher score that old premium ones.

Do you have any other idea how to make sure that premium offers are always on top of the list?

Comment: before suggesting i want to see your mappings/schema..?

Answer (score 0):

You can add Priority to Offers. And while indexing them give highest priority to premium offers and then new offers will get the second highest Priority.And all you need is to sort by priority. And then, you wont have to calculate function score and dont need to write scripts.

Comment: Well... I need to sort by `_score` because as you can see I use decay function. Besides filtering, I also search within index so sorting by `_score` is "MUST HAVE" :)